# how to get value from fallbackvalue?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn, fallbackvalue

I have the following DataGridTextColumn:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Example" IsReadOnly="True" 
                      Binding="{Binding Ex, FallbackValue='ExampleValue'}" />
```

the itemSource of the dataGrid is an ObservableCollection of some class A(that has a string Ex field).
I want Ex to be set to "ExampleValue", how do I do that?

Comment: What is ExampleValue here ?

Comment: the Ex is a string, so in some object of class  A, the Ex field = "ExampleValue" - that's what I want to happen..

Comment: To get value you can write `( string )( dGTest.Columns[0] as DataGridTextColumn ).Binding.FallbackValue;`. But I think it's not what you wanted. `FallbackValue` is used if Binding fails and value is unset. Why you can't set default value for `Ex` field then you initializing `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: If ExampleValue is some property in VM you can bind it using Element Name or relative Source

Comment: I can set default value for ex, but I have multiple data grids, and each of them work on the same class A(different observable collections but same class), and in each I want a different value to Ex, now I could just make a new classes that extends the original one, but I have many datagrids,  so I thought maybe there is an easier way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. If bindings is `OneWay` you can try to write several `ValueConverters` for display default value, maybe it's simpler to do.